# Get time left in sleep() in C

Tags: c, operating-system

I want to write a program to print the time slept during the sleep() function, 
This doesn't work as it only prints after it wakes up.

How can it print during sleeping? Do I have to use concurrency?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int snooze(unsigned int secs);


unsigned int snooze(unsigned int secs){
  unsigned int timeleft = sleep(secs);
  printf("Slept for %d of %d secs\n", secs - timeleft, secs);
  return timeleft;
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  snooze(5);

}
```

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to loop from `0` to `secs - 1` and call `sleep(1)` each time…

Comment: Think the problem througn. If you're going to take a half-hour nap, and you wake up every minute to check to see how long it's been, you're not really taking a half-hour nap, are you? You're taking 30 1-minute naps. The same applies here, as minitech says. (It is often helpful to think about the problem in real-world terms, and then figure out how to apply that to your code.) So if your code is sleeping for 10 seconds, and you want to report every second that passes, you need 10 1-second sleep periods instead.

Comment: ya, you right, but in the man page of sleep function, it returns the seconds left to sleep. So, why can't I get that value?

Comment: I guess I have to use a signal?

Comment: Timothy, I think it adds that return value for "spurious wakeups".  So if you want to be guaranteed to snooze the correct amount of time, you'd loop, sleeping for the remaining time (having initialized remaining time to "secs" to begin with) until remaining time was less than or equal to zero.
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)

Comment: The return value is well described on the man page I found. (And it's exactly what @Jmc thought it was.) This suggests you should add a `while` loop in the snooze function, in case you woke up too early. However, it's inconsequential to your original problem. To *print* something, you need to wake up. For more control, you could save the initial clock time when starting to sleep and then check if it's >= start+snooze time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some code that will send signals to it, this variant on your code (I called it `sleepers-awake.c`) will work:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static sig_atomic_t caught = 0;

static void snooze(unsigned int secs)
{
    unsigned int timeleft = secs;
    printf("Sleeping for %u\n", timeleft);
    while ((timeleft = sleep(timeleft)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Slept for %d of %d secs (signal %d)\n", secs - timeleft, secs, caught);
        caught = 0;
        printf("Sleeping for %u\n", timeleft);
    }
}

static void catcher(int signum)
{
    signal(signum, catcher);
    caught = signum;
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT, catcher);
    snooze(5);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Mini-Bombardier

Miniaturized program to run another program and bombard it with signals at 1 second intervals.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        return 1;
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        char *argv[] = { "./sleepers-awake", 0 };
        execv(argv[0], argv);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute %s\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            sleep(1);
            kill(pid, SIGINT);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
Sleeping for 5
Slept for 0 of 5 secs (signal 2)
Sleeping for 5
Slept for 1 of 5 secs (signal 2)
Sleeping for 4
Slept for 2 of 5 secs (signal 2)
Sleeping for 3
Slept for 3 of 5 secs (signal 2)
Sleeping for 2
Slept for 4 of 5 secs (signal 2)
Sleeping for 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to periodically wake up and note how much time you have left to sleep, you can do the following:

```
void snooze(unsigned int secs)
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    while(time(NULL) < start+secs)
    {
        sleep(1);
        int elapsed = time(NULL)-start;
        printf("Slept for %d of %d secs\n", elapsed, secs);
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't find this method a very restful way to sleep. :-)

If you simply wanted to guard against waking up too early, you could change the `sleep(1)` to `sleep((start+secs)-time(NULL))`, I suppose.